# Inverse texture mapping

Tags: texture, projections, 3dtexture

I have a textured 3D object and looking for ways to transform back the texture. Effectively, I think this is an inverse texture mapping task. Do you know of anything close to this? Some papers or implementations that already solved this task you know of?

As has been asked: The background is a "complex 3d object" (think of the shape/form of a non-regular potato, for example). Now, that object is randomly textured at run-time and I would like to restore that texture to the 2d space for further analysis (using machine learning techniques).

Comment: Do you have the screen coordinate positions of the vertices + UV values,  or are you also wanting to solve/synthesise those as well?

Comment: @SimonF thanks for that good question: did not know what UV means, but just discovered that there is also the concept of "UV maps"... if you have something that can figure out the screen coordinates + UV map itself that would be great, else it is possible to design them beforehand

Comment: I'm just trying to understand more precisely what the problem is that you're trying to solve. Perhaps you could add a diagram/image to your question?

Comment: Question edited to give some more background information.